# please give Help In tkinter buttons

Tags: python, tkinter

In my code which is attached along bottom, I want that the button1 which I have created will only come to normal state when the user selects one of the two options in option menu
but I am unable to find out how to do it so please help me.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from tkinter import messagebox as md
from tkinter import ttk
from pyttsx3 import *
from PyPDF2 import *
import os


win = Tk()

win.geometry('500x500')
win.title('AudioBook')

top_frame = win.frame()
bottom_frame = win.frame()
vari=StringVar()

def select_file():
    global file
    if vari.get() == 'WORD DOCUMENT':
        file=fd.askopenfilename(initialdir='/',filetypes=[('Word FILE','*.docx')])
    elif vari.get()== 'PDF DOCUMENT':
        file=fd.askopenfilename(initialdir='/',filetypes=[('PDF FILE','*.pdf')])

drop=OptionMenu(win,vari,'WORD DOCUMENT','PDF DOCUMENT')
button1=Button(win,text='Select File',command=select_file,state=DISABLED)
drop.pack(pady=10)
button1.pack(pady=10)

win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new function to check if the string is **empty** or **non-empty** owing to the fact that the non-empty strings have Falsy values.

```
...
def enale_disabled(*args):
    if vari.get():
        button1.config(state='normal')
    else:
        button1.config(state='disabled')

drop=OptionMenu(win,vari,'','WORD DOCUMENT','PDF DOCUMENT',command=enale_disabled)
...
```

In the above code, I have included an extra `''` in `OptionMenu` to give a better demonstration on how the button would be enabled or disabled.

In the function, use implicit booleaness to check if the string is empty or not. Then accordingly, change the state of the button.

Answer (score -1):

> I want that the button1 which I have created will only come to normal
> state when the user selects one of the two options in option menu.

The problem can be fixed by adding parameters and adding `state` in the `Button` dictionary in select_file(choice) function.

Snippet:

```
def select_file(choice):
    choice = vari.get()
    print(choice)
    
    if choice == 'WORD DOCUMENT':         
        file=fd.askopenfilename(initialdir='/',filetypes=[('Word FILE','*.docx')])
        button1['state']='normal'         
    elif choice == 'PDF DOCUMENT':
        file=fd.askopenfilename(initialdir='/',filetypes=[('PDF FILE','*.pdf')])
        button1.config(state='disabled')
```